# Как реализовать поиск по нескольким аттрибутам в EAV модели Yii2?

Tags: yii2, eav

Поиск по одному атрибуту получается все работает, а вот по нескольким атрибутам как делать поиск не могу догнать((

```
$productsQuery = Product::find()->joinWith('values')
->andWhere(['product.category_id' => $category->id])
->andWhere(['like', 'value.value', '%'.$size])
->andWhere(['value.attribute_id'=>$sizeAttrId])->all();
```

здесь выбираются продукты по 'размеру' а как выбрать по размеру по цвету итд по нескольким атрибутам?

Answer (score 0):

Добавлять

```
->andWhere(['product.color' => $colorFromForm])
->andWhere(['product.property' => $propertyFromForm])
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]